# Paypal dynamic dropdown for custom price list

Tags: php, paypal

I tried a lot but couldnt come up with the solution. I have some custom prices stored in my DB and want to retrieve them so that they can be included in the paypal dropdown list. My price list on the database keeps changing. So the code that paypal provides us is not working quite fine for me. What might be the possible solution?

I am using this code provided by paypal.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">

<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="8E58CWWNZP3PU">

<table>

<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Card Worth">Select Wash Card Value:</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">

            <option value="Card 1">$10.00 USD</option>

            <option value="Card 2">$25.00 USD</option>

            <option value="Card 3">$50.00 USD</option>

            <option value="Card 4">$100.00 USD</option>

            <option value="Card 5">$200.00 USD</option>

            <option value="Card 6">$300.00 USD</option>

            <option value="Card 7">$400.00 USD</option>

            <option value="Card 8">$500.00 USD</option>

<option value="Card 9">$1500.00 USD</option>

</select> </td></tr>

</table>

<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit"

alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">

<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">

</form>
```

Comment: Are you saying that you need to dynamically create the prices dropdown depending on your database data, and not use fixed values?

Comment: @GarethL yea.. thats what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample dynamic drop down

First you'll need a function to retrieve stuff from database

```
public function retrieve_all_accounts() {  /*open bracket retrieve_all_accounts*/

    $accounts_query = "SELECT ba.BankAccountID, bat.BankAccountType FROM BankAccount ba INNER JOIN
    BankAccountType bat ON ba.BankAccoutTypeID = bat.BankAccountTypeID WHERE UserID = " . $this->memberid;
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $accounts_query);

        return $result;
```

Then you'll have to create to create an array out of the database results

```
$accounts = retrieve_all_accounts();
```

Then here is the dynamic drop down.

```
  <label for="deposit_account">Account</label>
            <select id="deposit_account" name="account">
                <option value="0">--SELECT ACCOUNT--</option>
                <?
                    while($account = mysqli_fetch_assoc($accounts)) {
                        echo '<option class ="deposit_accounts" value="'. $account['BankAccountID'] . '">' . 
                        $account['BankAccountType'] . ' #' . $account['BankAccountID'] . '</option>' . "\n";
                    }
                ?>

            </select>
```